# How to use concept of multiprocessing with Mask RCNN?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, python-multiprocessing, opencv3.0

Currently I have a scenario in which I have a frame and I am performing a mask `rcnn` on it. This process is quite slow. I want to use multiprocessing in this process such that if in a particular frame if there are 3 or 4 probable regions of an object then using multiprocessing each region is assigned to a processor and after in the end all results get combined.

I am doing all this in Opencv 4.0 and python 3.6.Can anyone help me regarding that?

Comment: So, what is your question? How to perform second detection stage after RPN in multi-thread fashion, or what?

Comment: @user10981548 means if there are 3 regions in a frame then each region is processed by an individual thread.